# Activiti 5.15.1 process definition work on activiti 7.0.0.SR1 version without any change like schema and other?

Tags: activiti

Activiti 5.15.1 process definition work on activiti 7.0.0.SR1 version without any change like schema and other??

i have used timer,usertask,servicetask and many other design module in process details can it work same on activiti 7.0.0.SR1.

````
    <definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/test">
       <process id="process_1008964" name="LIVE_Concurrent_Test" isExecutable="true">
          <documentation>LIVE_Concurrent_Test</documentation>
          <startEvent id="sid-E96B49EC-9561-41E9-AC59-627BE682FFFE" name="Start" />
          <exclusiveGateway id="sid-75196864-A7A0-4AAB-BBE2-E85FB9326AE8" name="WG1" />
          <sequenceFlow id="sid-B531B6D4-7763-4896-B5C3-59253C1044DC" sourceRef="sid-E96B49EC-9561-41E9-AC59-627BE682FFFE" targetRef="sid-75196864-A7A0-4AAB-BBE2-E85FB9326AE8" />
          <sequenceFlow id="sid-419AF958-90C7-4B6A-8FDC-F56DB9EA8901" sourceRef="sid-75196864-A7A0-4AAB-BBE2-E85FB9326AE8" targetRef="sid-479CD653-2F42-43EF-A0C7-DB9E46D4930E" />
          <exclusiveGateway id="sid-98C40E57-1F36-44F5-8275-ECDE8EC0933F" name="EG2" />
          <sequenceFlow id="sid-658D1F52-2672-44B8-88CE-0DD58FB24049" sourceRef="sid-479CD653-2F42-43EF-A0C7-DB9E46D4930E" targetRef="sid-98C40E57-1F36-44F5-8275-ECDE8EC0933F" />
          <userTask id="sid-E2155826-C044-4ED2-9BD3-913B523F6E35" name="for ACK" activiti:assignee="U:413101" activiti:dueDate="P2D" activiti:formKey="15105:true" />
          <sequenceFlow id="sid-892FC477-9BFA-4D83-B476-1D13A037E624" sourceRef="sid-98C40E57-1F36-44F5-8275-ECDE8EC0933F" targetRef="sid-E2155826-C044-4ED2-9BD3-913B523F6E35" />
          <endEvent id="sid-98916D7A-D22F-48F3-B9AC-54744EFB0EA5" name="End" />
          <sequenceFlow id="sid-41FAE8D5-9D8A-4A5E-AE2C-48EC5F61DD6F" sourceRef="sid-E2155826-C044-4ED2-9BD3-913B523F6E35" targetRef="sid-98916D7A-D22F-48F3-B9AC-54744EFB0EA5" />
          <endEvent id="sid-7D33572E-CFD6-4BE4-B16A-569F72EE7898" name="End" />
          <sequenceFlow id="sid-7ECBC68A-4138-4C69-A55F-7D0117B8E6D4" sourceRef="sid-75196864-A7A0-4AAB-BBE2-E85FB9326AE8" targetRef="sid-7D33572E-CFD6-4BE4-B16A-569F72EE7898" />
          <endEvent id="sid-875F2FB4-6A94-4AF3-8023-F34AE9D0B953" name="End" />
          <sequenceFlow id="sid-86678BAE-860F-4020-BD49-5B935AF999AD" sourceRef="sid-98C40E57-1F36-44F5-8275-ECDE8EC0933F" targetRef="sid-875F2FB4-6A94-4AF3-8023-F34AE9D0B953" />
          <userTask id="sid-479CD653-2F42-43EF-A0C7-DB9E46D4930E" name="ST CH" activiti:async="true" activiti:assignee="U:413101" activiti:dueDate="P2D" activiti:formKey="15112:true" />
       </process> ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can work, if you find problems please report them in GitHub.com/activiti/activiti/issues
As we explained in Gitter, you are jumping 2 major releases, so major changes had happened.